# Woocommerce - Calculate Exta Fee Based on Amount of People

Tags: woocommerce, cart

I've added in a function for a custom field on the product general options:

```
// Add Custom Field to Product under General
function create_extra_fee_field() {
 $args = array(
 'id' => 'park_fee',
 'label' => __( 'Natl Park Entrance Fee', 'tranq-lsx-child' ),
 'class' => 'tranq-custom-field',
 'desc_tip' => true,
 'description' => __( 'This sets the Fee that will be added to the car.', 'tranq-lsx-child' ),
 );
 woocommerce_wp_text_input( $args );
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_options_general_product_data', 'create_extra_fee_field' );

// Save Custom Field Data
function save_extra_fee_field( $post_id ) {
 $product = wc_get_product( $post_id );
 $title = isset( $_POST['park_fee'] ) ? $_POST['park_fee'] : '';
 $product->update_meta_data( 'park_fee', sanitize_text_field( $title ) );
 $product->save();
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_process_product_meta', 'save_extra_fee_field' );
```

I would like to add this as an extra fee to the **Cart Totals** which multiplied based on the amount of **Person/People** that were selected from the Woocommerce Bookings.

Something like this:

```
// Calculate Extra Fee Based on Amount of People.

add_action('woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees' , 'add_custom_fees');
function add_custom_fees( WC_Cart $cart ){
$park_fee = get_post_meta($item['product_id'] , 'park_fee', true);

foreach( $cart->get_cart() as $item ){
   $fees += $item[ 'park_fee' ] * 14706; 
}

if( $fees != 0 ){
    $cart->add_fee( 'Park Fee', $fees);
}
}
```

How do I go about in achieving this? Any Links to a walkthrough would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I've added this and it seems to work:

```
// Add Custom Field to Cart Totals

function woo_add_cart_fee() {

    global $woocommerce;    

    foreach( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ){
        // Get the WC_Product object (instance)
        $product = $cart_item['data'];
        $product_id = $product->get_id(); // get the product ID
        $custom_field_value = get_post_meta( $product->get_id(), 'park_fee', true );
        $person = array_sum( $cart_item['booking']['_persons'] );
    }   
    $additional_fee_name = "Natl Park Entrance Fee";
    $extra_fee = $custom_field_value * $person;
    $addedFee = false;
    // first check to make sure it isn’t already there
    foreach ( $woocommerce->cart->get_fees() as $_fee )
    {
        if ($_fee->id == sanitize_title($additional_fee_name) )
        {
        $_fee->amount = (float) esc_attr( $extra_fee );
        }
    }
    if (!$addedFee)
    {
        $woocommerce->cart->add_fee( __($additional_fee_name, "woocommerce"),
        $extra_fee, $additional_fee_taxable );
    }
}

add_action( "woocommerce_before_calculate_totals", "woo_add_cart_fee" );
```